# Convert a list to a matrix or array?

Tags: r

```
  > str(mylist)
         List of 50
      $ : logi [1:14] 0.2 0.3 0.2 ...
      $ : logi [1:14] 0.1 0.3 0.6 ...
      $ : logi [1:14] 0.2 0.9 0.1 ...
```

I want to convert (or write out) `mylist` to 14 matrices with dim `5 10`
or one array with dim `5 10 14`

Example data:

```
mylist <- lapply(1:50, function(i) sample((1:14)/10, 14, repl=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This will produce the desired array (with NAs for the nonnumeric values):

```
array(as.numeric(unlist(mylist)), dim=c(14, 5, 10))
```