# How to reproduce image using writeJPEG from the mean of all elements in a nested array in R

Tags: r, computation

I have a nested array with a complicated structure. This array is a collection of 15 people, each with 11 images taken portraying 11 facial expressions such as wink, happy, etc.

I would like to calculate the mean images of 15 people with their 11 images taken.

[image]

The structure of `all.faces` is:

```
> str(all.faces)
List of 165
 $ : int [1:159, 1:159] 48 50 51 50 50 53 57 55 50 47 ...
 $ : int [1:159, 1:159] 159 156 131 130 117 115 122 119 123 129 ...
 (... and 163 more...)
  [list output truncated]
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 11 15
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:11] "centerlight" "glasses" "happy" "leftlight" ...
  ..$ : NULL
```

When I tried

```
myarray <- array(as.numeric(unlist(faces)), dim=c(159, 159, 15))

mean.faces <- apply(myarray,1:2, mean)
writeJPEG(mean.faces,"MEAN_FACES.jpg")
```

I got this:

[image]

How come? I would assume that I would some sort of image, not a mess of black and white color scheme like this.

**Reproducible example**

```
faces <- readMat("https://github.com/angelleng/545dump/blob/master/yalefaces.mat?raw=true")
faces.array <- array(as.numeric(unlist(faces)), dim=c(159, 159, 15))

mean.all.faces <- apply(faces.array,1:2, mean)
writeJPEG(mean.all.faces,"MEAN_FACES.jpg")
```

What is the best way to approach this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `apply` would work, except that would require your data to be in an 3d array, not a list.

Comment: @Axeman How can I handle this case with a list?

Comment: @AdamRalphus See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/37436412/6574038

Comment: @jay.sf I updated my post.

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @markus I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  `writeJPEG()` needs a matrix of values between 0 and 1.  You're giving it the raw data which has values in the range 0-255.

In detail, the example you gave (`yalefaces.mat`) has dimensions:

```
> faces <- readMat("https://github.com/angelleng/545dump/blob/master/yalefaces.mat?raw=true")
> dim(faces[[1]])
[1]   48   42 2414
```

so it's actually 2414 faces of size 48x42.  We can display one like so:

```
> image(faces[[1]][,,1])
```

[image: a face]

If you average them (without trying to resize the array, of course):

```
> mean.all.faces <- apply(faces[[1]], 1:2, mean)
> image(mean.all.faces)
```

it seems to work fine:

[image]

But when you write it out to a JPEG, the following will give garbage:

```
> writeJPEG(mean.all.faces, "BAD.jpg")
```

[image]

while the following works (though it's a little dark):

```
> writeJPEG(mean.all.faces/255, "GOOD.jpg")
```

[image]